# Paint something in JFrame after an event occurred?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, paint

How can I paint something in a frame in an event handler in java? Because I want to write the game Breakout and there I would need to repaint the entire screen in the event handler.

```
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e, Graphics g)
    {
        // if mouse was moved then rearrange paddle 
        double x = e.getX() - paddle_width;
        double y = e.getY() - paddle_height;
        this.repaint();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        g.fillRect(x, y, paddle_width, paddle_height);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your drawing panel extending JPanel and override the paintComponent.

Then you can have a model (By model i mean the data about what you want to paint)

Then you can add MouseMotionListener which would manipulate your model.

Notify the model changes to the drawing panel so that it will update the painting based on the model changes.

The below code should help you progress.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Demo extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo frame = new Demo();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Demo() throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Point start = new Point(0, 0);
        Paddle paddle = new Paddle(start, 20, 20);
        DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(paddle);
        setContentPane(drawingPanel);
        pack();
    }

    class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

        private Paddle paddle;

        public DrawingPanel(Paddle paddle) {
            super();
            this.paddle = paddle;
            this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(paddle.point.x, paddle.point.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            paddle.point = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            repaint();
        }

    }

    class Paddle {
        Point point;
        Integer height, width;

        public Paddle(Point point, Integer height, Integer width) {
            super();
            this.point = point;
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't follow you because I do not know what you mean by drawing panel and model. Could you maybe give me some code

Comment: @RaulRao give some time i will provide you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that